# How to give hexadecimal input to SHA256 in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sha256, sha

I'm trying to get SHA256 output for hexadecimal values but only able to give string input.
The Python 3 code I use is given below

```
from hashlib import sha256
hash = sha256(b'0x01')
hx=hash.hexdigest()
print('hx: ', hx)
```

What I get

```
hx:  b51c80e50d664f281fedd07ba902a21caadc0c7e0b491ece679497391e9f84cf
```

What I expect

```
hx:  4bf5122f344554c53bde2ebb8cd2b7e3d1600ad631c385a5d7cce23c7785459a
```

The expected output is from the online tool [SHA256 Online](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256.html) with input type as hex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the hexadecimal string to bytes using [`bytes.fromhex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex):

```
from hashlib import sha256
hash = sha256(bytes.fromhex('01'))
hx = hash.hexdigest()
print('hx: ', hx)
```